# View files stored in the app folder

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I've started using the Google Drive Android API in my app and have managed to get it to create files and save them to the app folder.

Is there any way I would be able to view these files in Google Drive, so I can check their contents (to check for bugs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, per the [App Folder documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder):

> The App Folder is a special folder that is only accessible by your application. Its content is hidden from the user and from other apps

You can, of course, add a debugging mode/UI to display the files within your own app.